Importing resource to replace terraform official module
I have a resource created using official AWS terraform module, like:
module "my-module" {
    source = "terraform-aws-modules/efs/aws"
}

Now, I want to convert that to a resource, like:
resource "my-resource" {
}

Which I want to be an EFS. I already have an EFS created through module, official one, not my custom one. Is there a way to perform terraform import and replace module with resource in this case?

If Backend for TFstate is going to be same then there is no need to terraform import. You can simply change it to resource from module just make sure all the configurations you mention in resource are same as the module

Hi, thanks, I will try that out

Sure! It should just work fine with the same configuration as the module.
